# Squirrelmail apache forbidden page

Tags: php, apache, squirrelmail

I am using PHP 7.0.5 and Apache 2.4.20 and I would like to run Squirrelmail.

I am getting a 403 Forbidden error when I try to access any of the squirrelmail pages like HostName/squirrelmail, HostName/squirrelmail/src/login.php or HostName/squirrelmail/src/configtest.php ect.

In my httpd.conf I have:

```
 Alias /squirrelmail /usr/local/squirrelmail/www
<Directory /usr/local/squirrelmail/www>
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Would you please let me know document root for Host name ?

Comment: Most likely cause is a permissions issue on the content. It looks like a Unix/Linux system - what are the filesystem permissions / ACLs and SELinux attributes?

Comment: The Apache root is /usr/local/apache/htdocs. I am trying to host the content from /usr/local/squirrelmail/www. I will check the access rights of the squirrelmail folders when I'm at work tomorrow.

Comment: I have changed the permissions of the squirrelmail folder to rwx for user group and others, but it din't solve the problem. When I moved the squirrelmail folder inside the apache/htdocs I could execute the php scripts without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to httpd 2.4 access control has changed from the previous version
the solution is as follows

> Order allow,deny Allow from all

should be replaced by:

> Require all granted

then restart httpd

> systemctl restart httpd

Answer (score 1):

You must check the log of Apache to solve the problem, in centos 7 the logs will be in tow pathes:

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Or

```
/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log
```

**In generally Apache vhost.conf file must contain this lines:**

```
Alias /webmail /usr/share/squirrelmail

<Directory "/usr/share/squirrelmail">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride none
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
</Directory>
```